# Font-Size for star-character in firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css

I am trying [this](http://codepen.io/lsirivong/pen/ekBxI) solution for a star rating.

Can someone please explain why the stars are so much bigger in chrome than in firefox? (I know that webkit and gecko are doing different things from time to time but so much difference?)

And has someone a suggestion on how to fix that?

---

Update:
This is how big the difference is on my mac:
[image]

Comment: Can you not use `em`? it will be better if you use `px`. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the characters in different fonts in different browsers. The size of a character may well very by font (even when the font size is the same).

The technique uses the characters “★” U+2605 BLACK STAR and “☆” U+2606 WHITE STAR, which are present in a few [fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/fontsupport.htm) only. If the `font-family` property on the relevant element does not mention any font containing those characters, browsers will (or at least should) use some backup font, and different browsers use different lists of backup fonts.

You can make it more probable (though not certain) that different browsers in the same system use the same font for the characters by listing suitable fonts in the `font-family` list. Even then, the results will vary by system, depending on the set of installed fonts. And in some systems, the rendering may even fail, because no font contains those characters.

This issue could be addressed using downloadable fonts, but that would probably be overkill here.

The practical workaround is to use just images, with a sequence of elements like `<img src=star.png alt=star>` and `<img src=whitestar.png alt="">` or (for better accessibility) a pre-made image that contains a specific number of stars, like `<img src=stars4.png alt="four stars out of five">`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and have found that using U+2B51 and U+2B52 ("BLACK SMALL STAR" and "BLACK WHITE STAR") displays consistently between Chrome and Firefox. (Haven't tested thoroughly across other browsers and browser versions yet though.)

Answer (score 0):

May be it's strange for you.. But I dont find any difference in the browsers.

find attached image.[image]

Comment: This is even more strange. On my system the difference is much bigger. I updated my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Characters in different browsers may vary. Use image as star. Not char. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzRQw.png use {content:''; background:url(....) no-repeat;}

Comment: Can you please show me how to rewrite this piece of code to use an image?